# How to resize view using UIModalPresentationFormSheet on iOS 8

Tags: ipad, ios8

looks all the old workaround for resizing the view (from sheet style) doesn't work on IOS 8.

Any other solutions ?

for example, the below code works on iOS 7, but not IOS 8.

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]        initWithRootViewController:viewController]; navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet; 
navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil]; 
navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 544);
navigationController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally found a solution on the iOS 8, need to implement the -(CGSize)preferredContentSize on each view controller.